# ng build giving error related to Rxjs module

Tags: angular, build, rxjs, rxjs-observables

While doing ng build, I am encountering some module error related to RxJs.

[image: Error in Ng Build]

Here is my package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-slider/ngx-slider": "^2.0.3",
    "@angular/animations": "^11.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/material": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "~10.2.5",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.2.2",
    "@types/d3": "^5.7.2",
    "angular-google-charts": "^0.1.6",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "countries-map": "^4.2.0",
    "crypto-js": "^3.3.0",
    "d3": "^5.14.2",
    "d3v4-bullet": "^1.0.7",
    "json-view": "^0.4.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "ng-circle-progress": "~1.6.0",
    "ng-otp-input": "~1.7.1",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "~7.0.0",
    "ngx-json-viewer": "^2.4.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^10.0.1",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^2.5.207",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1002.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.2.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.8"
  }
}
```

I tried many ways like degrading or upgrading the Rxjs Version in package.json but every time this error coming.
is there any way to fix this ?

Comment: It looks like you have a mistake in the dependency version here: `angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1002.3"`